# Is HTTPClient instances are not intended to be reused?

Tags: java, web-services

Is it a bad practice to re-use a single HTTPClient instance for every request? I make a `request` to get data from yahoo `webservice`, now in another page I make a `webservice` call to google.

Can I use the same HTTPClient instance in these two different pages or should I create new HTTPClient object for both?

Answer (score 6):

You should definitely reuse them and treat `HttpClient` as a singleton. Having single instances reused across the whole application makes it possible to take advantage of keep-alive connections and persist cookies between calls.

Quoting the [official documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/performance.html#Reuse_of_HttpClient_instance) for 3.x:

> Generally it is recommended to have a single instance of HttpClient per communication component or even per application. However, if the application makes use of HttpClient only very infrequently, and keeping an idle instance of HttpClient in memory is not warranted, it is highly recommended to explicitly  shut down the multithreaded connection manager prior to disposing the HttpClient instance. This will ensure proper closure of all HTTP connections in the connection pool.

The same applies to 4.x, just make sure to use [`PoolingClientConnectionManager`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingClientConnectionManager.html).